# How to create a custom \part in LaTeX book?

Tags: sectioning, book-design, books, parts

I am trying to create a custom `\part` for a book in `XeLaTeX`. I'd like to be able to have the Part number and title in larger font as is typically found. However, I'd also like to have a short paragraph beneath the part number and title.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,letterpaper,draft]{book}
\begin{document}
  \part{Custom Part}
  Text to be included as a paragraph below custom part. The text should be on the same page just under the heading. 
  \chapter{The first chapter}
  Here is my text for chapter 1. 
\end{document}
```

Here is an example from a book of something that I'd like to replicate.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A version without using a package. The `\partname` is shifted outside to the left margin!

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,letterpaper,draft]{book}

\newlength{\partheaderrulewidth}
\setlength{\partheaderrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\newlength{\leftheadingshift}
\makeatletter
\newbox\boxtemp


\def\@part[#1]#2#3{%
  \leftheadingshift\z@
  \setbox\boxtemp=\hbox{\nobreakspace}
  \addtolength{\leftheadingshift}{\wd\boxtemp}
  \setbox\boxtemp=\hbox{\huge\bfseries\partname}
  \addtolength{\leftheadingshift}{\wd\boxtemp}

  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
  \refstepcounter{part}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
  \else
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
  \fi
  \markboth{}{}%
  {%
    \parindent=0em
    \interlinepenalty \@M
    \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
    % Shift the partname to the margin (Release the box!)
    \hskip-\leftheadingshift\unhbox\boxtemp\nobreakspace\huge\bfseries\thepart%
    \par
    \vskip 10\p@
    \fi
  }    
  \parindent=0em%
  {\Huge\bfseries #2}%
  \medskip

  \rule{\linewidth}{\partheaderrulewidth}
  {\normalfont #3}
  \vskip-\smallskipamount
  \rule{\linewidth}{\partheaderrulewidth}
  \@endpart
}


\newcommand{\specialpart}[3][]{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\part[#1]{#2}{#3}}{\part{#2}{#3}}%
}

\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
  \specialpart{Custom Part}{Text to be included as a paragraph below custom part. The text should be on the same page just under the heading.}
  \chapter{The first chapter}
  Here is my text for chapter 1. 

  \specialpart[Foo]{Custom Part}{Text to be included as a paragraph below custom part. The text should be on the same page just under the heading.}
\end{document}
```

[image]